# Move content on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I am using the following jQuery to move content from the top of the main content column in mobile view to the top of the sidebar when in desktop view.

```
if (ww >= 768) {
  $( '#move-me' ).insertBefore($( '#top-widget' ) );
}
```

**Here's a fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/richerimage/co6nw6va/1/

This works fine on page load, but I'd like the content to be able to move back and forth on window re-size

Like all things, I guess this is easy if you know how! :)

Any help is greatly appreciated

With thanks

Richard

p.s. also, is there a way to move the content to the top of the `#sidebar` without the need to reference the `#top-widget`?

Comment: Might be easier and more efficient to do this with media queries. Put the content in *both* places with different classes, and show the appropriate version via media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    doThis();
});

$( window ).resize( function() {
    doThis();
});

function doThis(){
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (ww >= 768) {
        $( '#move-me' ).insertBefore($( '#top-widget' ) );
    }else{
        $( '#move-me' ).insertBefore($( '.post_content' ) );
    }
}
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/co6nw6va/7/)**

Comment: Thank you, please see above comment - same issue - works when going from small to large but not visa-versa

Answer (score 1):

So you need to use [`resize`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event handler:

```
$( window ).resize( function() {
    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (ww >= 768) {
        $( '#move-me' ).insertBefore($( '#top-widget' ) );
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/co6nw6va/3/)

Comment: Thank you - this works fine when making the window larger but not when going from a larger view to a smaller view. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you need to add `else` statement and do whatever you want on it.